# shape of a 1D array gives 'tuple' object is not callable?

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

Why do I get 'tuple' object is not callable for the following?

```
x=  np.array([2,3,6])
print(x.shape())
```

Comment: `x.shape` is a `tuple`.  A `tuple` is not callable.  Remove the `()` after `x.shape`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, remove the () after shape.

To further elaborate, x is an object, shape is its attribute, so you can get it by x.shape, which is a tuple (3,). If shape were a function, then you would be able to call it by x.shape().